# VS 2008 + Intel fortran - Debug: How to see automatically list of last variables calculated chronologically?

Tags: debugging, variables, visual-studio-2008, timeline, watch

This is probably a simple question, but:

> > is it possible to see the value for the last variables calculated as we go through the debugging process step-by-step?

I know I can set the variables I want in the Watch windows when debugging, or see the values of each variable during debugging by placing the mouse over the variable in the code, but this is annoying and time consuming.

The "Locals" window seemed initially that it could do the trick, but I only manage to make it show the variables in an order that is totally random, and I have hundreds of variables (many are arrays), so it becomes useless.

Any thought on this would be more than welcomed! :)

Best

Comment: I've used VS with Intel Fortran for several years and never found a way to do this.  I remain to be proven wrong but I don't believe it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply :) I'm guessing that there is no point on me researching more for this option then.. I cant understand is why this option does not exist in VS with Intel Fortran